# Bluetooth earbuds not connecting on dual boot arch linux and windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, bluetooth, arch-linux, dualboot

I'm having trouble with these bluetooth earbuds (Sony WF-C500) I've paired with arch linux and windows 10. The [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth) said that the pairing keys needed to be synced with windows in order to work on both OSes. I used [this tool](https://github.com/x2es/bt-dualboot) that it linked to automate the process, and it synced them successfully. I restarted bluetooth.service and pulseaudio, but the earbuds failed to connect on arch or windows. They had successfully connected to each when I first paired them. I then tried the manual process listed on the arch wiki page and double checked with the process given [here](https://console.systems/2014/09/how-to-pair-low-energy-le-bluetooth.html). The keys are identical on both OSes, so I'm not sure what step is missing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IMO you shouldn't do that. There's no problem at all in using the same BT peripheral with multiple devices, dual-boot is just a special case of "multiple devices" where the different device is technically the same machine but different. Worst case scenario you'll have to forget and pair again when and if it doesn't connect automatically.

Comment: So I should unpair them from each and try repairing without syncing?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Can you clarify what I shouldn't do? I unpaired and repaired the earbuds on each OS without syncing the keys and now they still won't connect. I'd like to avoid unpairing and repairing every time I switch between each OS.

Comment: I tought it was quite clear that what you shouldn't do is the part mentioned in the Arch guide.

Comment: Right, but when I tried that I encountered the same issue.